# Trying to start threads of a member function from within a class

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here's a quick outline of my class:

```
class foo{
public:
    vector<string> rawData;
    vector<vector<string> > slicedData;
    void readData();
    void sortData();
private:
    static void selectionSort(vector<string>);
};
```

Basically, `readData` populates `rawData` with information from an external file.  Once it does this, `sortData` splits that data into subsets, each of which is stored in `slicedData`.  I need to spawn a thread of `selectionSort` to sort each subset, and I have to do so inside of `sortData`.

I've tried it this way within `sortData`:

```
thread *threads = new thread[slicedData.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < slicedData.size(); i++){
    threads[i] = thread(selectionSort,slicedData[i]);
}
```

...but when I do so, g++ throws `error: attempt to use a deleted function`.

For the record, I need to store the threads in an array so I can join them later.  I realize this could be done more elegantly with the boost library and thread groups, but I'm trying to keep this project dependency-free.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: No, it does other things with the data as well, it just isn't necessary to include them as they aren't relevant to this issue.

Comment: I think you want something like `thread(&foo::selectionSort, this, slicedData[i])`

Comment: Still throwing the same error: `attempt to use a deleted function`.

Comment: You should provide a minimal working sample that can be compiled and that shows the error. I tried to create a small program based on what you described and could not reproduce the problem. As a side note - the way your methods are defined the strings will be copied over to each thread. This is obviously not what you want, Use vector<string> & as the argument to the thread procedure. You may also consider just passing itterators to the start and end of each segment and not create sub vectors

Comment: "attempt to use a deleted function" is not the whole error message. Provide the whole output, along with a minimal example. That said, use `new` to allocate an array is a bad idea, use a vector instead.

Comment: The error isn't in the threading code that you have shown here, it's either  in your implementation of  `selectionSort`, or more likely, your `sortData` method doesn't wait for the threads to complete, and your `foo` goes out of scope and gets deleted while the threads are still trying to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your error, but the following code compiles for me.

I would recommend using a *vector* of *threads* and calling *emplace_back()* to create the *threads* inside the *vector*..

Something like this:

```
class foo
{
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > slicedData;

    void sortData()
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

        // for each slice add a new thread passing the function and data
        // to its constructor
        for(auto& slice: slicedData)
            threads.emplace_back(&foo::selectionSort, std::ref(slice));
            // NOTE: use of std::ref() to pass by reference

        // now join the threads to prevent the threads vector
        // going out of scope before they finish
        for(auto&& thread: threads)
            thread.join();

    }

private:
    static void selectionSort(std::vector<std::string>&); // pass by reference
};
```

Also note I pass the data by *reference* because I suspect you don't really want to sort a copy of the data.

Comment: Spelling: *emplace* back.

Comment: This works!  I believe it did have to do with my not joining the threads back correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't in the threading code that you have shown here. Probably, your `sortData` method doesn't wait for the threads to complete (use `thread.join` as Galik described), and your `foo` goes out of scope and gets deleted while the threads are still trying to use it. That's why you see "attempt to use a deleted function"